# Programatically create a 3D model (of a door)

Tags: 3d

I must generate 3D models of doors using various:

1. assemblies (tenon, 45 degres)
2. Frames
3. Panel

If I have 2 assemblies, 10 types of frames and 10 types of panels, I must generate 200 models. I have chosen to neglect other parameters that influence look (wood grain orientation, wood species, texture …)

I build a simplified prototype using three.js. Having no experience with this type of work, I was wondering what would be the best way to get started on this project considering that:

1. Models will be generated once (server side i.e. not dynamically)
2. All doors will be the same size.
3. I want to input a 2D model for the frame and the panel edges and "extrude" the shape.

Eventually, I want to clone and resize a door model to place them in a 3D model of a kitchen. This second phase will be done dynamically and client side.

How should I tackle this problem?

Are there open source libraries and tools to help me achieve my goal?

Comment: What language are you using

Comment: @TGKL I'm ok with c#, C++, Java, PHP, JS ...

Answer (score 0):

[vcglib](https://github.com/cnr-isti-vclab/vcglib) should work for you, it's a C++ library for visual and computer graphics. Take a look at its [samples](https://github.com/cnr-isti-vclab/vcglib/tree/master/apps/sample) and the [doc](http://vcg.isti.cnr.it/vcglib/index.html) on how to use the library.

A sample code of trimesh_allocate.cpp in the sample to add a vertex and face,

```
  // Alternative, more compact, method for adding a single vertex
  ivp[3]= &*vcg::tri::Allocator<MyMesh>::AddVertex(m,MyMesh::CoordType ( 1.0, 1.0, 0.0));

  // Alternative, more compact, method for adding a single face (once you have the vertex pointers)
  vcg::tri::Allocator<MyMesh>::AddFace(m, ivp[1],ivp[0],ivp[3]);
```